# Unable to register new IConnectionIdFactory

Tags: signalr

I'm trying to specify a new ConnectionIdFactory and have included the following code into global.asax's Application_Start method. I have references to both SignalR and SignalR.Hosting.AspNet assmeblies.

```
AspNetHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdFactory),
                                              () => new MyConnectionIdFactory());
```

The "Register" method shows a "Cannot resolve symbol 'Register'" on the editor. If I try to compile, I get

*'SignalR.Hosting.AspNet.AspNetHost.DependencyResolver' is not supported by the language*

**UPDATE 4/18:** Has anyone done this in 0.5? I want to try it in the latest codebase, but I know the AspNetHost namespace is deprecated in 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

[Jonas Stawski](http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2012/05/09/AspNetHost-deprecated-in-SignalR-0-5.aspx) says AspNetHost is deprecated in 0.5.

Instead, you can use:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register
```

Here is another [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2012/05/04/api-improvements-made-in-signalr-0-5.aspx) on the changes in 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out- It turns out I was running SignalR 0.5 with Signal.Hosting.AspNet 0.4. (face-slap). This happened because I was trying to use my own IConnectionIdFactory in 0.5 earlier, but couldn't figure it out so went back to 0.4. I thought I deleted all references, but I guess I missed something.

Hope this helps another lost soul.